# Using <= vs =. Assignment operator in a class task

Tags: system-verilog

I'm confused as to why I cannot use `<=` to assign variables inside my class?  I've used `<=` in tasks before, is this just a problem with fact that I'm assigning to a class local variable?  Here's the code in question:

```
package MyPackage;

class test;
  logic b_val;

  task set_val;
    //this.b_val = 1'b1;   // WORKS
    this.b_val <= 1'b1; // ERROR
  endtask
endclass // test

endpackage

module Test;
  import MyPackage::*;
  test t1 = new;

  initial 
    begin  
      t1.set_val;
    end  
endmodule : Test
```

The error I receive is:

```
# ** Fatal: (SIGSEGV) Bad handle or reference.
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Process: /Test/#INITIAL#18 File: C:/Projects/SystemVerilog/sim/test.sv
# Fatal error in Task MyPackage/test::set_val at C:/Projects/SystemVerilog/sim/test.sv line 8
```

Comment: Can you show a complete self-contained example?

Comment: @dave_59, I assumed this would have a quick answer.  I updated to show complete self-contained example.

Comment: You must be missing something. Your short 22 line example runs fine, but the error message you show is on line 283.

Comment: @dave_59, sounds like it's a tool issue then.  I updated the error to reflect the example I posted, it's still failing when using non-blocking assignment.

Comment: I can run 10.3a fine on linux. I don't have the windows versions set up.

Comment: Runs fine for me using VCS simulator at [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/LrC)

Comment: Looks to be a tool issue, change your simulator to Rivera and the error presents itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing non-blocking assignments to class members is a relatively new feature of SystemVerilog. You will need a version of the simulator released after 2012. Even still, I cannot reproduce your error in earlier versions.

Comment: Interesting... I'm using Modelsim 10.3a, which is dated 2014.

Comment: It's a tool issue.  See the comments above, it can be replicated on EDA Playground.